# Custom Email Template results an 'Inline image URL' as FeedItem subject

Tags: email-template, feeditem

I have the below Custom HTML Email Template, which incorporated our logo as a letterhead as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<table style= "width: 100%; background-color: #09C" cellpadding= '0' cellspacing= '0'>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">
<img alt="Support Logo" src="https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=xxxx&oid=xxxx"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
....
</body>
</html>
```

When we use this Email Template to send emails, the feed item has the following '[Inline image URL' declaration as a subject, instead of showing the first line of the actual Email Message:

[image]

This was reported as an 'idea' here - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cMKGQA2.

I wonder if there is a way to workaround this (would it be possible to make a Formula field with the Image) and add that to the Custom HTML Email Template)?